# Updating a JComponent in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, action

I have a JTabbedPane that looks like this:

```
 overview= new JTabbedPane();

            JComponent accountinfo= AccountOverview(guest.toString());
            overview.addTab ("Account Overview", accountinfo);
            overview.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);


            JFrame tabbed= new JFrame("AIR Reservation");
            tabbed.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            tabbed.add(overview);
            tabbed.setSize(650,500);
            tabbed.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            tabbed.setVisible(true);
        }
```

guest.toString prints out the customer's information. 
my AccountOverview(guest.toString) method looks like this:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);

    JButton editName= new JButton ("Edit Name");
    editName.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame nameframe= new JFrame("Name Edit");
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(nameframe, "Change name to: ");
                guest.setName(name);
            }
        });
    JButton editGender= new JButton ("Edit Gender");
    editGender.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame genderframe= new JFrame("Gender Edit");
                String gender = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(genderframe, "Change gender to: ");
                guest.setGender(gender);
            }
        });
    JButton editBirthday= new JButton ("Edit Birthday");
    editBirthday.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                JFrame birthdayframe= new JFrame("Birthdate Edit");
                String birthday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(birthdayframe, "Change birthdate to: ");
                guest.setBirthDate(birthday);
            }
        });
    JButton editPassportNumber= new JButton ("Edit Passport Number");
    editPassportNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
                JFrame passportframe= new JFrame("Passport Number Edit");
                int passnum= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(passportframe, "Change passportnumber to: "));
                guest.setPassportNumber(passnum);
            }
        });
    panel.add(editName);
    panel.add(editGender);
    panel.add(editBirthday);
    panel.add(editPassportNumber);
    panel.add(destination);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
}
```

I want to edit the JComponent so the tabbedpane reflects the new updated changes. 
For example, if the original display was "Name: Admin", a simple click of "Edit Name" and input of "John" would change the original display to "Name: John".

edit: My toString() method (comes from another class, Customer)

```
//Returns the Customer object as a String. 
public String toString()
{ 
    customerstring= "<html>Name: " + getName();
    customerstring+= "<br>Gender: " + getGender();
    customerstring+= "<br>Date of Birth: " + getBirthDate();
    customerstring+= "<br>Passport number: " +  getPassportNumber();
    customerstring+= "<br>Balance: " + money.format(getMoney());
    return customerstring;
}
```

How can I edit my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, the toString method is part of another class. I've edited my post to include this method. The code I originally posted is from my GUI class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In: `JComponent accountinfo = AccountOverview(guest.toString());`  you process the information to create your component.

This generates a copy of your guest information (by calling toString()) which can not be changed later on. Try passing the guest object to your component and do the toString() call every time it repaints itself.

Having the component repaint it self can be done by calling accountinfo.repaint() after an edit has been made.

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I pass the guest object to my component though?

Comment: Well somehow in the method AccountOverview() you create a Jcomponent. I would suggest to create a class (extends Jpanel or whatever you use) which has a field guest. Than whenever guest changes: make it repaint/refill whatever you do to create the component

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to this whole thing. Would I use a ChangeListener to see if guest changes? Sorry for all these questions but thank you :)

Comment: You can use a Changelistener or any other listener that fits your purpose (PropertyChangeListener is actually designed for this, but a bit too detailed to my taste, I never use it). Calling a self created method (something like updateComponents) after an edit is possible too, depends how many sources of change you have. In the end you will probably change some ui components, make sure to do that on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) by calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) Otherwise you get strange results.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I understand what to do now :)